# saving data to session storage with Ext.data.ArrayStore

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Could anyone give an example of storing array of model/objects recieved and parsed from Ajax Request in Ext.data.ArrayStore (session storage)?
At the moment I am only able to store it separately in session storage.

```
userModelProxyKey "0"
userModelProxyKey-0
"{"login":"username","locked":false,"internalUser":false,"name":"","email":"","sid":""}"
```

My model

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Model','./js/model');
Ext.require('Model.User');
Ext.define('Store.UserStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
         model: 'Model.User',
         storeId: 'userStore',
         proxy: {
             type: 'sessionstorage',
             id: 'userStoreProxyKey'
         }
});
```

My store

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Model','./js/model');
Ext.require('Model.User');
Ext.define('Store.UserStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
         model: 'Model.User',
         storeId: 'userStore',
         proxy: {
            type: 'sessionstorage',
            id  : 'userStoreProxyKey'
         }
});
```

Saving to model to session storage:

```
var user = Ext.create('Model.User', {'id':0,'login': jsonData.login});
user.save();
```

Attempting to save to storage

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Store.UserStore');
var userArray = new Array(user);
userStore.add(userArray);
userStore.sync();
```

and if I try to print number of records I get 0

```
console.log("User Count: " + userStore.count());
```

Comment: I think that you're looking for `Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage` and not `ArrayStore`.

Comment: thank you. I've switched back to Ext.data.Store and using sessionstorage now.